# PDO error: Can't initialize character set utf8_general_ci

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

PHP on my web host was recently updated and now my old MySQL queries are showing the "deprecated" error message.  I need to convert mysql_query code to PDO.  Here's what I am starting with:

```
<?

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
    if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); } mysql_select_db("database_name", $con);

        $result = mysql_query("select * from event_calendar where event_year >= '2017' order by event_datenumber asc")
        or die(mysql_error());

     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                $event_date = $row['event_date'];
                $event_month = $row['event_month'];
                $event_monthname = $row['event_monthname'];
                $event_year = $row['event_year'];
                $event_datenumber = $row['event_datenumber'];
                $event_starttime = $row['event_starttime'];
                $event_location = $row['event_location'];
                $event_city = $row['event_city'];
                $event_state = $row['event_state'];
                $event_directions = $row['event_directions'];

    $testmonth = date("F");
    $testmonth2 = date("m");
    $testdate = date("d");
    $testyear = date("Y");
    $testdatenumber = $testyear.$testmonth2.$testdate;

    ?>

    <?

    if ($testdatenumber <= $event_datenumber){

    ?>

    <p>
    <b><? echo $event_monthname.' '.$event_date ?></b> - <? echo $event_starttime ?><br>
    <? echo $event_location ?><br>
    <? echo $event_city ?>, <? echo $event_state ?><br>
    <a href="<? echo $event_directions ?>" target="_blank"><b>Directions</b></a>
    </p>

    <? } else {} ?>

<?  } ?>
```

I'm totally new to this and don't know where to start.  I also noticed that today it is now saying "No database selected" as well.

I've been atempting to rewrite this myself in PDO line by line and so far I am getting:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2019] Can't initialize character set utf8_general_ci (path: /usr/share/mysql/charsets/)' in /my_file_location/test-this.php:21 Stack trace: #0 /my_file_location/test-this.php(21): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=localhost', 'username', 'password') #1 {main} thrown in /my_file_location/test-this.php on line 21

My line 21, referenced in the error above, is as follows:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name;charset=utf8_‌​general_ci', 'username', 'password');
```

I've now changed utf8_general_ci to just utf8 and now have the following message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost'
>   to database 'database_name'' in /my_file_location/test-this.php:21
>   Stack trace: #0 /my_file_location/test-this.php(21):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=localhost', 'username', 'password') #1
>   {main} thrown in /my_file_location/test-this.php on line 21

My web host is using a Windows operating system, I believe, and the PHP version it was just upgraded to is 5.6.30 but I have no idea about the mySQL database.

UPDATE:  OK, after a few days reading and poking around, I have managed to come up with a working rewrite.  I now have the following working:

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name;charset=utf8mb4', 'username', 'password', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
                                                                                                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

    foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM event_calendar WHERE event_year >= 2017 ORDER BY event_datenumber ASC') as $row) {

    $testmonth = date("F");
    $testmonth2 = date("m");
    $testdate = date("d");
    $testyear = date("Y");
    $testdatenumber = $testyear.$testmonth2.$testdate;

if ($testdatenumber <= $row['event_datenumber']) {

    echo "<p>";
    echo "<u><h4>".$row['event_monthname']." ".$row['event_date'].", ".$row['event_year']."</h4></u>";
    echo "<b>What:</b> ".$row['event_title']."<br/>";
    echo "<b>Where:</b> ".$row['event_location']." - ".$row['event_address1'].", ".$row['event_city'].", ".$row['event_state']." ".$row['event_zip']."<br/>";
    echo "<b>When:</b> ".$row['event_starttime']."<br/>";
    echo "<b>When:</b> <a href='".$row['event_directions']."' target='_blank'><b>Click here</b></a>";
    echo "</p>";

    } else {}

    }

?>
```

Now I just wish I could figure out how to limit results to only the first three rows that meet the criteria.  I've tried several things so far but have not yet been successful.  I guess it's back to reading and testing until I find something that works.

Comment: the way to start is to read up tutorials on the internet about pdo, you don't just dump your old code here on stackoverflow and expect someone to just convert it for you straight up, how are you going to learn pdo if you won't start it yourself, you are clearly on the wrong place

Comment: This link [Migrate from MySQL Extension to PDO](https://www.sitepoint.com/migrate-from-the-mysql-extension-to-pdo/) maybe help you

Comment: Thank you, Yu Jiaao, for at least being kind enough to offer a link for info.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Great, would you add that into your question at the end, using code formatting? That is a much more focussed question. I've not come across that error. It's worth mentioning your operating system and version too.

Comment: (If this question closes, based on the current version, ping me after you've edited, and I will consider a reopen vote).

Comment: @halfer Thank you for the info.  I apologize for the tone of my response and didn't mean to ruffle feathers.  I just found Ghost's reply to be uncalled for, regardless of the potential reason you've given for it.  That's not an appropriate way to handle a request for assistance without first clarifying if someone is indeed looking for free work from others.

Comment: The best advice here is to be like a computer system: strict in your polite output, and forgiving in your input. Don't worry about it though, everyone takes things personally here and gets a bit more terse than they intended - happened to me the other day, and I thought I'd perfected the art of wearing Kevlar `:-)`.

Comment: Exposing a question with decent grammar, with great effort on explaining and still voted negative (-4) is the reason why the comunity is seen as toxic. The reason? new member. Gamification sucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: OK, after a few days reading and poking around, I have managed to come up with a working rewrite. I now have the following working:

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name;charset=utf8mb4', 'username', 'password', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
                                                                                                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

    foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM event_calendar WHERE event_year >= 2017 ORDER BY event_datenumber ASC') as $row) {

    $testmonth = date("F");
    $testmonth2 = date("m");
    $testdate = date("d");
    $testyear = date("Y");
    $testdatenumber = $testyear.$testmonth2.$testdate;

if ($testdatenumber <= $row['event_datenumber']) {

    echo "<p>";
    echo "<u><h4>".$row['event_monthname']." ".$row['event_date'].", ".$row['event_year']."</h4></u>";
    echo "<b>What:</b> ".$row['event_title']."<br/>";
    echo "<b>Where:</b> ".$row['event_location']." - ".$row['event_address1'].", ".$row['event_city'].", ".$row['event_state']." ".$row['event_zip']."<br/>";
    echo "<b>When:</b> ".$row['event_starttime']."<br/>";
    echo "<b>When:</b> <a href='".$row['event_directions']."' target='_blank'><b>Click here</b></a>";
    echo "</p>";

    } else {}

    }

?>
```

Now I just wish I could figure out how to limit results to only the first three rows that meet the criteria. I've tried several things so far but have not yet been successful. I guess it's back to reading and testing until I find something that works.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is clear: there is no such charset. And never has been.

`utf8_general_ci` is a *collation*, while you need a *character set* here, which is called as just <s>`utf8`</s> or, rather, nowadays it should be `utf8mb4`.

Let me recommend you my [PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) which will help you to avoid a lot of confusions like this.

Comment: Thank you.  I made the change to utf8 and now get an access denied message.  I will check out your tutorial.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score -1):

The correct *immediate* solution is to disable the showing of errors on your live site. This should be done anyway, since you *never* want to expose that information to users:

```
ini_set('display_errors', false);
```

Do not do this on your non-live (test) sites, as you want to see errors there.

Once you have put this in place on your current site, your task to migrate away from this old database extension will be less urgent. My guess is that you're now on PHP 5.6, which still supports the `mysql_` functions, but you will still need to prepare for 7.x, where they have been removed.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Yes, it appears to be PHP 5.6.30